# Is there any evidence of a Jewish demon named Khoyzek?

Tags: names, demons, jewish, linguistics

The Yiddish term *khoyzek* refers a "mockery" of something else. According to Dov Sadan (cited [here](https://groups.google.com/g/jewish-languages/c/fQgby_9d0-Y/m/0cfgeyNABAAJ)) this word derives from Khoyzek a demon in Jewish folklore. I looked high and low and could not find any evidence of a demon name Khoyzek in any Jewish (or even non-Jewish sources). Does anybody know of any sources which mention such a demon?

Answer (score 2):

Sadan's article is discussed in depth [here](https://www.academia.edu/41214120/Selective_Confusion_or_The_Ghoti_Principle_in_Yiddish_Linguistcs_Eastern_Ashkenazic_Yiddish_khoyzek_non_Eastern_chausek).

Yiddish is a thousand-year-old Jewish language, with origins, according to a broad scholarly consensus, in the German Rhineland. The major component of Yiddish, in both its Western and Eastern varieties, is Middle High German, with varying admixtures of Slavic, Hebrew, and other languages. There are many words that clearly have a Hebrew origin in Yiddish, like *meylekh* (“king”), *azes* (“brazenness”), *kheyshek* (“desire”), *menukhe* (“rest”), *metsiye* (“bargain”), *sod* (“secret”), *tomer* (“whether”), *miyes* (“ugly”), *yakres* (“expensiveness”), *nakhes* (“satisfaction”), *shoyte* (“fool”), *kol* (“sound”), *mishpokhe* (“family”), *tsure* (“face”), etc.

The origin of *Khoyzek* in Eastern Yiddish, pronounced *chausek* in Western Yiddish, is unclear.

Much of the confusion stems from an old theory, which states that khoyzen derives from *cheisik*, a word first mentioned in Philoglottus with the German meaning *belustigung*, meaning "amusement". [Hans Peter Althaus](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/334034823_YIDDISH) translates *Belustigung* as (in Hebrew letters)

חשק

which also renders *cheisik* according to the [Yiddish dialect dictionary](https://yiddishdialectdictionary.com/khes-%D7%97%D7%AA/).

A more modern theory links *khoyzek* with modern Eastern Yiddish *kheyshek* (lust).

Note that both theories revolve around German translations that contain "lust", from Middle High German *lust*, from Old High German *lust*, from Proto-Germanic *lustuz*. Cognate with English *lust*, West Frisian *lust*, Dutch *lust*. Interestingly, lust etymologically can mean both *pleasure* and *desire*, the latter for example in the Yiddish expression:

> Isch wil un hob cheischek. ‘I want it because I want it.’

However, we also have this Yiddhish idiom, which suggests the origin of the word may be Germanic:

> Versmakht khoyzek oys dir, dem zol onvaksn a khoyzek oyf der noz

which in modern German would render something like:

> Wer macht khoyzek aus dir, dem zoll anwachsen eine khoyzek auf der nase

which means

> He who makes fun (khoyzek) of you, let a khoyzek grow on his nose

This makes absolutely no sense, unless you take into account that the older Yiddish form of the word is **chausek* meaning "fortress". Now the German word for "fortress" is *schlosz*, which can also refer to female genitals. Interestingly, there is also a link with "nose" in German:

> schlosz nennt man auch an den pferden das ende der nase (*schlosz* is also the name for the nose-bridge of horses)

So clearly the idiom is wordplay on the different meanings of *khoyzek*.

It is with this consideration that we can identify the origin of the "demon" association, which starts with Jeremiah 20:7

[image]

> Thou hast persuaded me, O Jehovah, and I am persuaded; Thou hast hardened me, and dost prevail, I have been for a laughter all the day, Every one is mocking at me,

The link is "everyone is mocking at me". The Dead Sea Scrolls version of the text of Jeremiah quotes some of Jubilees where שעירים ([se'irim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Se%27irim)) may have been the Hebrew word in Jub 1:11, which was then rendered in Ethiopic Jubilees as *demons*.

*Se'īrīm* are frequently compared with the *[shedim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shedim)* of Hebrew tradition, along with *satyrs* of Greek mythology and *jinn* of Arab culture

For an in-depth explanation, see Tigchelaar's [Jeremiah’s Scriptures in the Dead Sea Scrolls](http://file:///C:/Users/bob/Downloads/Article%20Ascona%20Tigchelaar.pdf)